# $\lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^x$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'm  a bit rusty with limits
but my book says that

$$ \lim_{x \to -\infty}\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^x= e$$
and I don't agree completely, knowing that
$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$

In my opinion the right result should be $1/e$ but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Your limit does not depend on $n$, should it be $x \to \pm \infty$?

Comment: What does $n$ do in this stuff?

Comment: I beg your pardon.....I've edited the text

Comment: To help convince yourself, you can plug in $x = 1000$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the $x$ in the exponent also goes to $-\infty:$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} (1 + \frac 1 x ) ^ x = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac 1 x ) ^{-x} = \frac 1 {\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac 1 x) ^ x} = \frac 1 { \frac 1 e} = e$$

Answer (score 0):

(From Demidovich book) The statement is true. In general if $\lim_{x\to a}f (x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\pm\infty$, then
$$\lim_{x\to a}f (x)^{g (x)}=e^{\ \displaystyle{\lim_{x\to a}(\,f(x)-1)g(x)}} $$

Answer (score 0):

The general formula is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac ax\Bigr)^x=\mathrm e^a,$$
and its proof relies on the high-school limit:
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+au)}u=a,$$
which corresponds to the very definition of the derivative of the function $\ln(1+au)$.